# Why css class is not overridden for IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, conditional-comments

I have piece of HTML code in which we are applying special css for IE9, IE10 & IE11.

```
<!doctype html>
     <!--[if IE 9]><html data-placeholder-focus="false" lang="{%=user_locale_html}}" dir="ltr" class="ie9 lt-ie10 lt-ie11 lt-ie12 gt-ie8 gt-ie7 gt-ie6"><![endif]-->

     <!--[if !(IE)]><!--><html lang="{%=user_locale_html}}" dir="{%=dir}}">

<script>

  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

  if (ua.indexOf("Trident/7.0") > 0) 
    document.documentElement.className='ie11 lt-ie12 gt-ie10 gt-ie9 gt-ie8 gt-ie7 gt-ie6';
  else if (ua.indexOf("Trident/6.0") > 0)
    document.documentElement.className='ie10 lt-ie11 lt-ie12 gt-ie9 gt-ie8 gt-ie7 gt-ie6';

  if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){
    document.documentElement.className='gt-ie11 gt-ie10 gt-ie9 gt-ie8 gt-ie7 gt-ie6';
  }

</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
</html>
```

**Note the code `if(/*@cc_on!@*/false) {}`**

This code is overriding the css class applied in IE10 when we have `userAgant=Trident/6.0.` (Which causing me problem to override `ie10` class.

But my question is, **Why this code is not overriding the classes when the browser is IE9?**

I know that @cc_on related stuff is not needed in the code, But i am curious to know how it is behaving differently.

Thanks!

Comment: IE 9?! I'm surprised anyone even attempts to support IE 9 in 2019

Comment: `cc_on` has some [**very** flaky support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/at-cc-on). You probably shouldn't be trying to use this at all

Comment: You need to use the cross browser solution for IE9 have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp toggle class name here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Comment: Conditional comments are also no longer supported by almost all browsers. I haven't seen code trying to do this kind of thing for a long time. Almost everyone just supports "modern" browsers these days

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply guys :)
I understand the thing that whatever is done here is seems deprecated. And of course, it's a 5 years old code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible that your code is not identifying the IE 9 and that is why CSS class not get override.

I suggest you to try to refer code example below which can able to find the IE 8, IE 9, IE 10, IE 11.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <script>
 function GetIEVersion() {
  var sAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var Idx = sAgent.indexOf("MSIE");

  // If IE, return version number.
  if (Idx > 0) 
    return parseInt(sAgent.substring(Idx+ 5, sAgent.indexOf(".", Idx)));

  // If IE 11 then look for Updated user agent string.
  else if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) 
    return 11;

  else
    return 0; //It is not IE
}

if (GetIEVersion() > 0) 
   alert("This is IE " + GetIEVersion());
else 
   alert("This is not IE.");
 </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify it as per your requirement may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Your code seems good, But i wanted to know that your MSIE keyword will work in all the cases of IE11?
Because i have seen here https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/internet-explorer/

That IE11's userAgent string will not contain MSIE all the time.

Comment: I try to test this code with several OS and IE 11. Based on my testing result, I find that this code is working fine with Win 7, Win 8.1, Win 10, Win Server 2012, Win Server 2016, Win Server 2019. It is able to identify the version of IE when I change the document mode from developer tools.

Comment: Thank you for answering